# Not able to setup SmartGit with bitbucket in Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, bitbucket, smartgit

I installed [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/) and I am able to log into my BitBucket account, while trying to clone the repository I keep seeing this error

```
Could not connect to the reposotory https://username@bitbucket.org/username/xyz

PLease check the reposotory URL

reposotory https://username@bitbucket.org/username/xyz not found: remote:Not Found
```

Why am I seeing this error? When the login works and it is the Smartgit that is displaying the list of repository that I have and when I select that this error appears, I cant seem to get past this error.

If I copy the repository URL in browser it takes me to the repository, i even tried copying the URL bitbucket provides in case someone wants to clone it and even that does not work in smartgit.

In my office computer where I use windows I was able to get it up and running in no time using the SAME URL with SAME login details

At this point I am pretty frustrated and clueless. Any help will be really appreciated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check log.txt in SmartGit's settings directory (see About dialog) to find our more details about the error and paste the relevant section here. Also, what happens when trying to `git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/username/xyz` from command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it to work.

I did not realize that the repository I had setup was Mercurial and not Git and while in Windows SmartGit does not seem to have problem detecting it but in Ubuntu other steps were required before Mercurial repository can work.

Make sure you have Tortoisehg setup in Ubuntu otherwise Mercurial wont work, you can visit [this](https://mcmblog.azurewebsites.net/how-to-install-tortoisehg-on-ubuntu/) article on how to install it.

Once that is done, make sure to setup Executable path in Smartgit.

To access Executable settings go to Menu `Edit->Preferences`

[image]

It seems that once the **Hg Executable** is setup correctly only then while cloning `Mercurial` option shows up other wise you will be going crazy thinking where is `Mercurial` option to clone a repository.

[image]

This is how I got it to work.

Comment: I am not using SmartGit, but I had the same problem trying to "git clone" a Mercurial repository... ;)